# What is this component labelled AOH?

Tags: identification, components

What is this component? It's labeled AOH. It's in my rechargeable fan pcb (I think the pcb performs both charging functions and speed control of the motor).

[image: Picture of an unknown SMD transistor/Mosfet labelled AOH]

Comment: With the designator Q, it's a transistor.

Comment: I've seen this before and in the case that I've face to, it was a N-channel MOSFET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is labelled **AQH**.

It might be a PNP or NPN transistor from Chinese manufacturer Galaxy Microelectronics. They have very similar marking for several of their SOT23. They have lots of them but no search by marking feature.

https://www.gmesemi.com/product-en/?pgsl=search&cid=36